# Inconsistent results from NSURL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurl

Using the following code to make my requests, what i've noticed is that data will sometimes not be loaded or fully loaded, this always happens when the app first starts. Any thoughts? I've tried putting in [tableView refresh] in the connectionDidFinishLoading, but that doesn't seem to help, any ideas? Thanks for looking

```
.h:
    NSMutableData *responseData;

.m:
    - (void)load {
        NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL
                                                 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                             timeoutInterval:60];

    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [responseData release];
    [connection release];
    [textView setString:@"Unable to fetch data"];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[responseData
                                                   length]);
    NSString *txt = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];

}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that the NSLog messages tell me that I am getting all of the data eventually, but I think the problem has to do with the way i'm refreshing the UITableView. One thing I am struggling with is that I am getting the data in my app delegate, but i'm not sure how I can [tableView reloadData] on the RootViewController within the app delegate? – Hoofamon 0 secs ago edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your data did not load? Try `[tableView reloadData];` instead of `refresh`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that the NSLog messages tell me that I am getting all of the data eventually, but I think the problem has to do with the way i'm refreshing the UITableView. One thing I am struggling with is that I am getting the data in my app delegate, but i'm not sure how I can [tableView reloadData] on the RootViewController within the app delegate?

Comment: That all depends on how you set things up. Why is your app delegate receiving the data, and not the RootViewController? I would just make the root view controller the delegate and add the required methods there.